# V-model не работает с jquery масками

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Когда убираю маску для полей phone и discount, v-model:discont и v-model:phone - работает корректно ( переменные динамически изменяются при вводе новых данных), с масками ничего не работает. Как исправить?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
   $("#phone").mask("+7 (999) 999-9999");
});
jQuery(function($){
   $("#discont").mask("99");
});
```

```
 <li>
                                <form method="POST" class="form-inline">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                           <div class="input-group input-group-md">
                                               <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-percent"></i></span>
                                               <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
                                                   <input type="text" v-model="discont" placeholder="скидка" class="form-control" id="discont">
                                               </div>
                                           </div>
                                </form>   
                         </li>
                         <li>
                                <form method="POST" class="form-inline">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                           <div class="input-group input-group-md">
                                               <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                               <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
                                                   <input type="text" v-model="phone" placeholder="телефон" class="form-control" id="phone">
                                               </div>
                                               <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" @click.prevent="findClient(phone)" type="button">!</button>
                                               </span>
                                           </div>
                                       </div>
                                </form>   
                         </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте установку значения для model в одном из событий `inputmask` плагина
`onComplete` или `onKeyPress` или `onChange`. Это происходит из-за того, что `inputmask` внутри работает со своим `value`, из-за этого могут возникать конфликты с биндингом данных на vue и не только.

Comment: Я новичок, подскажи пожалуйста как в коде это правильно сделать, спасибо!

Comment: Выясняю проблему до сих пор, дело в том, что jquery не генерирует события в том же самом формате что и vue, так что насколько я понял решение должно быть в генерации события, делаю что - то типо такого, но пока не работает

Comment: Выложите ваш код на jsfiddle, помогу